# Captions not working in VideoJS in Flash IE8

Tags: flash, video, internet-explorer-8, amazon-s3

I'm having problems getting captions working with VideoJS from VTT files hosted on Amazon S3.

An example is shown below. If I server the VTT file locally then it works fine. If I try it in Firefox it also works fine. It just seems to be a problem with IE8.  I'm serving the file as text/plain from S3.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
          controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
          poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">
         <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
         <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
         <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
         <track kind="captions" src="http://twig-video-captions.s3.amazonaws.com/demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default>
        </video>

        <script>
            var vid = videojs("example_video_1", {
                techOrder: ["flash","html5"]
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```